# Searching for a prefix in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, search, prefix

I'm currently writing a spam-checker. One aspect of it is the bad-link-checker.
I have a large-ish database (a few millions) of known-to-be-bad URL *prefixes*, extended quite often, and I'd like to compare any URL I get against this database very quickly - the kind of thing I'd probably do with a trie if memory was not an issue.

Database example:

- `evil.example.com`
- `innocentlookingblog.com/compromisedpage`
- `baduser@gooddomain.com`

Now if the URL I get is `innocentlookingblog.com/compromisedpage/you-have-won.exe`, I want to quickly determine that it's a bad URL because `innocentlookingblog.com/compromisedpage` is a prefix.

Is there a good way to do this in PostgreSQL? As far as I can tell, none of the index types seem to be designed for this kind of search in which the table contains the prefixes and the data contains the full text.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a filter condition to reduce the number of matches. Assuming that all prefixes are at least 10 characters long, create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON spammers (substr(prefix, 1, 10));
```

Then query like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM spammers
WHERE substr(prefix, 1, 10) = substr('theurl.com/something', 1, 10)
  AND 'theurl.com/something' LIKE prefix || '%';
```

The first condition can use the index and will reduce the number of hits considerably.